# Detecting a mobile device with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mobile

I am trying to get my application to detect a mobile device and render that page but I am getting no response but my index.html page is rendering. It is completely ignoring my mobile controller.

```
@Controller
public class DeviceDetection {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public @ResponseBody String detectDevice(Device device) {

        if (device.isNormal()) {
            System.out.println("Inside isNormal()");
            return "index";

        } else if (device.isMobile()) {
            System.out.println("Inside isMobile()");
            return "mobilePage";
        } else if (device.isTablet()) {
            return "mobilePage";
        }
        return "index";
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mobile</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring-boot-mobile` requires additional property to be set in order to detect your `Device`.

The property is `spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.enabled: true`

The following is default directories structure:

```
        resources
        └── templates
            └── greeting.html
            └── mobile
                └── greeting.html
            └── tablet
                └── greeting.html
```

In your case you need to map your templates correctly.

Spring Boot `spring-mobile` properties to customize behavior:

*`spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.enable-fallback=false`* - Enable support for fallback resolution.

*`spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.enabled=false`* - Enable device view resolver

`spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.mobile-prefix=mobile/`- Prefix that gets prepended to view names for mobile devices.

*`spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.mobile-suffix=`*- Suffix that gets appended to view names for mobile devices.

*`spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.normal-prefix=`* - Prefix that gets prepended to view names for normal devices.

*`spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.normal-suffix=`*- Suffix that gets appended to view names for normal devices.

*`spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.tablet-prefix=tablet/`*- Prefix that gets prepended to view names for tablet devices.

*`spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.tablet-suffix=`*- Suffix that gets appended to view names for tablet devices.

*`spring.mobile.sitepreference.enabled=true`*- Enable SitePreferenceHandler.

Also I would change `@RequestMapping("/")` to something else.

Comment: That is already added. Sorry I forgot to add it to my question

Comment: @Drew1208 Updated my answer.

Comment: I added /index to my `@RequestMapping` and got it to work but it only renders the string `mobilePage` in the browser. I thinking I need a `resourceViewResolver` but I am not sure.